# Go package linkage with a C library

Tags: c, go, linkage, cgo

I hope this is a basic question. I am trying to build a Go package which includes functions from a library written in C. The structure is basically as follows:

```
package too

/*
#cgo LDFLAGS: -L/usr/local/lib include -lbar
#include mybar.h
*/
import "C"

func MyGoWrapper () {
  C.orig_func()
}
```

Running `go build foo.go` fails with an "undefined reference" for `orig_func`. *Note that the header is `mybar.h`*; I created a prototype for `orig_func` that was not included in the original library. Do I need to recompile the library first, including this header file, before it will link with the Go build? Or am I misunderstanding something else entirely?

Comment: I have no cite, but I don't think Go allows cross-compilation when using cgo.

Comment: [Does now.](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=4714) However, you need some gnarly settings to do so, possibly environment variables `CGO_ENABLED=1` and `CC_FOR_TARGET`/`CXX_FOR_TARGET` (gcc/g++ for target platform) and maybe even something like `-ldflags="-extld=$(CC)"` passed to `go build`. This isn't an answer because I don't know if it's true -- I'm going entirely by comments there.

Comment: For `-lbar` to work, you need `libbar` to be installed for your target arch (`go build` won't build and install it for you), and I'm suspicious of the `-L/usr/local/lib`--I think you might instead have a separate `lib/` somewhere else with libraries targeting other architectures.

Comment: (One way around some of the linker excitement, if the library is pretty self-contained, is to dump the entire library's source into your package like, say, https://github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3 does.)

Comment: @twotwotwo I did look at go-sqlite3 as an example, but the library I need is too big to dump into the repository like that

Comment: Oh, actually, I can answer your direct question: you do need to recompile the library for the target platform. Rewriting this in the other box then.

Answer (score 4):

When linking against an external library, you do need to separately compile it for your target architecture. `cgo` can't replace the `configure`/`make` (or whatever) to compile the library; it only knows how to build a few `.c` files in your package directory, and a library's build process might be more complex.

---

I'm less sure of how to accomplish the larger task of linking in an external library when cross-compiling (and I'm not sure what you've already done). [The (closed) Go bug on cross-compilation with `cgo` looks useful here.](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=4714) You may want to *build the Go toolchain* with some environment variables set that are described in [`godoc cmd/cgo`](http://golang.org/pkg/cmd/cgo):

> To enable cgo during cross compiling builds, set the CGO_ENABLED
>       environment variable to 1 when building the Go tools with make.bash.
>       Also, set CC_FOR_TARGET to the C cross compiler for the target. CC will
>       be used for compiling for the host.
>
> After the Go tools are built, when running the go command, CC_FOR_TARGET
>       is ignored. The value of CC_FOR_TARGET when running make.bash is the
>       default compiler. However, you can set the environment variable CC, not
>       CC_FOR_TARGET, to control the compiler when running the go tool.
>
> CXX_FOR_TARGET works in a similar way for C++ code.

The bug also mentions someone who uses `-ldflags="-extld=$(CC)"` (where `$(CC)` is the name of the cross-compiler they want to use).

In your example code there's an explicit `-L/usr/local/lib` and I don't think that'll work: I think when you build libraries for the target, you're going to want to put them in a directory distinct from the `lib` for your host arch. For example, [this ARM cross-compilation HOWTO](https://www.ailis.de/~k/archives/19-arm-cross-compiling-howto.html)  uses a `/usr/local/arm-linux` prefix or install_root in some places.

Comment: this is a good answer to my question as originally stated. However, it turns out that cross-compilation is not an issue in my case. I will update with more details; as for now, @twotwotwo, you've provided an excellent explanation of cross-compiling with cgo. Thanks!